# Date condition in R language only formatted till 1/12/2011

Tags: r, date

I have stored my csv file in dataframe called  "data".

```
> data[1,]

        atm_name transaction_date no_of_withdrawals no_of_cub_card_withdrawals
1 Big Street ATM         1/1/2011                50                         20
  no_of_other_card_withdrawals total_amount_withdrawn amount_withdrawn_cub_card
1                           30                 123800                     41700
  amount_withdrawn_other_card  weekday festival_religion working_day
1                       82100 Saturday                 H           H
  holiday_sequence
1              WHH
```

I want to create a data frame containing data between the date "1/1/2001" and "1/29/2011". The following command is loading the data into variable k till "1/12/2011". The format of my date is "%m/%d/%Y".

```
k <- subset(data, as.Date(transaction_date) > '1/1/2011' & as.Date(transaction_date) < '29/1/2011' )

> head(k$transaction_date);
[1] 1/1/2011 1/1/2011 1/1/2011 1/1/2011 1/1/2011 1/2/2011
2427 Levels: 1/1/2011 1/1/2012 1/1/2013 1/1/2014 1/1/2015 1/1/2016 ... 9/9/2017
```

The five same dates are coming because I have 5 different atm_name for a single day.

```
> tail(k$transaction_date)
[1] 9/11/2017 9/12/2017 9/12/2017 9/12/2017 9/12/2017 9/12/2017
2427 Levels: 1/1/2011 1/1/2012 1/1/2013 1/1/2014 1/1/2015 1/1/2016 ... 9/9/2017
```

The tail should be five records with date ***"1/29/2011"*** but it is going and storing the last records i.e. till ***"9/12/2017"***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several flaws in the posted code.

1. `as.Date(transaction_date)` *without* format specification will return wrong values, e.g., `as.Date("1/1/2011")` will result in `1-01-20`. According to `help(as.Date)`, `as.Date()` will try `"%Y-%m-%d"` then `"%Y/%m/%d"` if not specified.
2. `as.Date(transaction_date) > '1/1/2011'` compares an object of class `Date` with a character string which might give unexpected results due to implicit type conversions.
3. `29/1/2011` is a date format which is inconsistent with OP's own definition `"%m/%d/%Y"`.

Please, try

```
# coerce character (actually factor) dates to class Date
data$transaction_date <- as.Date(data$transaction_date, "%m/%d/%Y")
# subsetting
k <- subset(data, transaction_date > as.Date("2011-01-01") & 
              transaction_date < as.Date("2011-01-29"))
```